# Add Server classes to android.jar

Tags: android, api

Right now I am able to get access to the hidden and internal android APIs, but now I want access to things like `AlarmManagerService` which is in server.  I used `adb pull system/framework/services.jar` changed `services.jar` to `services.zip` which unpacked a directory of all the server classes (including AlarmManagerService which I was looking for).  My question now is how can I add those server classes to my `android.jar` file which I can then use in Eclipse?

I hope that makes sense the way I worded it.  Let me know if there is any confusion I can clear up.

EDIT:  Essentially, when all is said and done, I want to be able to do something like below without any errors:

```
import com.android.server.AlarmManagerService;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AlarmManagerService ams = new AlarmManagerService(this.getApplicationContext());
        ams.setTime(1313);
    }
}
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

I figured this out after looking at all the source code.

Classes like AlarmManagerService just have package visibility which is why it cannot be imported. Some classes are public, but many other com.android.server classes have package constructors so they can't be instantiated.

Here are the com.android.server.* I was able to import and successfully create an object of:

```
import com.android.server.AttributeCache;                   
import com.android.server.BootReceiver;                     
import com.android.server.BrickReceiver;                    
import com.android.server.ClipboardService;                 
import com.android.server.ConnectivityService;              
import com.android.server.DevicePolicyManagerService;       
import com.android.server.DiskStatsService;                 
import com.android.server.DropBoxManagerService;            
import com.android.server.EntropyService;                   
import com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService;        
import com.android.server.LocationManagerService;           
import com.android.server.MasterClearReceiver;              
import com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException;   
import com.android.server.NetStatService;                   
import com.android.server.NotificationPlayer;               
import com.android.server.ProcessMap;                       
import com.android.server.ProcessStats;                     
import com.android.server.SystemBackupAgent;                
import com.android.server.SystemServer;                     
import com.android.server.ThrottleService;                      
import com.android.server.TwilightCalculator;               
import com.android.server.Watchdog;                         

import com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering;           

import com.android.server.status.AnimatedImageView;
import com.android.server.status.CloseDragHandle;
import com.android.server.status.DateView;
import com.android.server.status.ExpandedView;
import com.android.server.status.IconMerger;
import com.android.server.status.LatestItemView;
import com.android.server.status.NotificationData;
import com.android.server.status.NotificationLinearLayout;
import com.android.server.status.StatusBarService;
import com.android.server.status.StatusBarView;
import com.android.server.status.StorageNotification;
import com.android.server.status.TickerView;
import com.android.server.status.TrackingPatternView;
import com.android.server.status.TrackingView;
import com.android.server.status.UsbStorageActivity;
```

Answer (score 1):

android.jar contains only the public API's class files and I think you made changes in 'com.android' package or its internal packages. So to reflect the changes in eclipse you have to add the path explicitly to your service.jar to your project. But remeber this will not reflected at run time, since the emulator or the device you are using have not been updated your changes. And you can't update them by simply modifying the jar file, since the device or emulator uses the image 'system.img' which internally have .dex file as library not the .jar file for internal APIs. To make changes for device/emulator you have to build the whole code and for that you can refer the http://source.android.com/source/index.html.

Comment: So originally, Eclipse uses this thing called `android.jar`.  Mine happens to be in `/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-8` directory.  I made a duplicate of `android-8` directory, called it `android-8-internals` and then replaced the `android.jar` which originally only contains the public API with my own `android.jar` which contains all the internal and hidden APIs.  It works fine. I am able to access all the hidden and internal APIs just fine

Comment: Now I want to do it for classes in the server directory, and when I did the same thing, even though I see the `com.android.server` in eclipse, I am not able to do something like `import com.android.server.AlarmManagerService;`.  I cannot figure out what this is.

Comment: The `AlarmManagerService` class is just the implementation of `IAlarmManager.aidl`. The AlarmManagerService is sigleton, hence the object of AlarmManagerService you get can also be get directly from the `Activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);` Hence there is no need to import it.